# merge and match two csv files with .net

Tags: .net, excel, csv

i've got two csv files that i want to merge. Basically, i've got my source file, and the second file will add information to that file using a primary key that they both share.

I've done this using v-lookup but since this will be a weekly process, i want to automate it using vb.net or C#. any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: If you are able to use SSIS (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Integration_Services) I would definitely check it out. It was build for jobs such as these.

Answer (score 1):

It is quite possible to use SQL with CSV files in either vb.net or c#.

Some notes:

```
cn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
            "Data Source=c:\docs\;" & _
            "Extended Properties=""text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited"""
cn.Open()

cmd.Connection = cn
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT a.PK, b.SText,a.[Processor Time] INTO BookX.csv " & _
            "FROM [Book1.CSV] a " & _
            "LEFT JOIN [Book2.CSV] b " & _
            "ON a.PK = b.PK"
```

Comment: This looks like something i can do, i'll give it a shot.