# How to get more performance for merging files

Tags: c#, csv

I have  500 csv files , 
each of them's size is about 10~20M.

for a sample , the content in file like below ↓

file1 :

```
column1 column2 column3 column4 .... column50
```

file2:

```
column51 column52 ... ... column100
```

So , What I want to do  is merge all the files in to one large file like below ↓

fileAll

```
column1 , column2 ......  column2500
```

In my solusion now is

```
1, Merge per 100 files into  5 large files

2, Merge 5 large files into one large file
```

But the performance is very bad.

So , Can anyone give me some advice to improve the performance ?

Thanks !

Comment: What does your code look like?

Comment: Thanks for your post , I just wonder an idea first .. I would put my code if need... :)

Comment: This seems like a really good example of where the TPL should give you performance improvements because you can merge any two files separately. Albeit, if you write too frequently, performance will be worse. Also, check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4074857/merge-and-match-two-csv-files-with-net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What language are you working in, Off the top of my head, I would think you would get the best performance by doing a line by line stream.

So for instance, read the first line of all the files in, write the first line of the merge out. Continue until your done.

The reason why this is better than your solution is your solution reads and writes the same data to and from disk several times, which is slow.  I assume you can't fit all the files in memory, (and you wouldn't want to anyway, the caching  would be horrible), but you want to minimize disk reads and writes(the slowest operation) and try to do it in a fashion where each  each segment to be written can fit in your cache.

All so, depending on what language your using, you may be taking a Huge hit on concatenating strings.  And language that is using null terminated arrays as its string implementation is going to take a huge hit for concatenating large strings because it has to search for the null terminator.  python is an examples off the top of my head.  So you may want to limit the size of the strings you work with.  In the above example, read in x many chars, write out x many chars ect ect.  But you should still only be reading the data in once, and writing the data out once if at all possible.

Answer (score 1):

You could try doing it as a streamed operation; don't do 1. Load File 1, 2. Load File 2, 3. Merge, 4. Write Result. Instead do 1. Load line 1 of File 1 & 2, 2. Merge Line, 3. Write line. This way you speed things up by doing smaller chunks of read, process, write and thereby allow the disk to empty its read/write buffers while you do the merge of each line (row). There could be other things slowing down your process. Pls post code. For example, string operations could easily be slowing things down if not done carefully. Finally, Release mode (as opposed to Debug) is more optimized and will typically run significantly faster.